# How to assign list key with value in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
lista = vector(mode = 'list', length =2)
listname = c(0.1,0.2)
names(lista) = listname
for (i in listname){lista[[i]] = i}
```

> Error in lista[[i]] <- i : 
>         attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

I want to get a list with key = (0.1,0.2) and assign value to those keys in a for loop

Comment: What value do you want to assign to list elements? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Try `for (i in 1:length(listname)){lista[[i]] = i}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @RonakShah's comment in that it's not very clear what you're trying to do.

I assume that

1. you have a `list` (called `lista`) with a k `NULL` elements, and
2. you have a `numeric` vector (called `listname`) with k elements.

I further assume that you're trying to (1) name every `lista` element with names given in `listname`, and (2) replace every `NULL` element with the corresponding entry from `listname`.

You can do this in one step using `Map` and `setNames`:

```
setNames(Map(c, lista, listname), listname)
#$`0.1`
#[1] 0.1
#
#$`0.2`
#[1] 0.2
```

---

### Sample data

```r
lista <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
listname <- c(0.1, 0.2)
```

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: You're very welcome @Amy. Since you're new around here, please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant posts. It also provides a small reputation bonus to both the question poster and answerer. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Done. Thanks for the orientation.